# Database crashed and Redis stop alone

Tags: database, redis

After some moment from starting Redis Server (Usually 15 Hours), The table Posts crashed (The service “mysql” was down.)

```html
Service Name

mysql

Service Status

failed ⛔

Notification

The service “mysql” appears to be down.

Service Check Method

The system’s command to check or to restart this service failed.

Number of Restart Attempts

1

Service Check Raw Output

(XID cxnub3) The “mysql” service is down.

The subprocess “/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_mysql” reported error number 255 when it ended.

Startup Log
```

And When I checked I found That Redis is stop. "I faced this issue more then 5 times" And every time I try to change redis.conf like maxmemory and maxmemory-policy. But nothing help. The database size is 300mb and website's posts is 4800 , so Is there any change should I made to fix this issues.

Comment: What is the OS? Is it a Linux?

Comment: Yes, it's CentOs 7.

Comment: Both processes are shutdown after 15 hours?

Comment: Yes, Exactly, Both them.